# longest common subsequence using memoization

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, memoization

This program is of longest common subsequence using memoization. But it is giving answer 0 for the below example. Before adding memoization, it was giving correct answer 2.

I think I did mistake in adding memoization. Can anyone help me with what is wrong with this code?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
 char a[100]="bd",b[100]="abcd";
 int lcs1[100][100];

 int lcs(int i,int j){
     int temp;
     if(lcs1[i][j]!=-1)

     if(a[i]=='\0'||b[i]=='\0'){
        return 0;
     }
     if(lcs1[i][j]!=-1)
        return lcs1[i][j];
     else if (a[i]==b[j])
        temp = 1+lcs(i+1,j+1);
     else
        temp = max(lcs(i+1,j),lcs(i,j+1));
     lcs1[i][j] = temp;
     return temp;

 }
 int main(){

     int temp = lcs(0,0);
     memset(lcs1,-1,sizeof(lcs1));
     printf("%d",temp);

 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend cleaning up to your code to use spacing between operators and braces for your conditionals (which appears to be the cause of one of your logic errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems:

- you were initialising the memoization array after calling `lcs()`
- you had an extra `if` in the beginning of your `lcs()`

Here is corrected code:

```
#include<cstring>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
 char a[100]="bd",b[100]="abcd";
 int lcs1[100][100];

 int lcs(int i,int j){
     int temp;
     //if(lcs1[i][j]!=-1)       // problem 2

     if(a[i]=='\0'||b[i]=='\0'){
        return 0;
     }
     if(lcs1[i][j]!=-1)
        return lcs1[i][j];
     else if (a[i]==b[j])
        temp = 1+lcs(i+1,j+1);
     else
        temp = max(lcs(i+1,j),lcs(i,j+1));
     lcs1[i][j] = temp;
     return temp;

 }
 int main(){
     memset(lcs1,-1,sizeof(lcs1));  // problem 1
     int temp = lcs(0,0);
     printf("%d",temp);

 }
```

<sub>Note: that it is a good practice to avoid global variables. Try to capsulate them in structures or classes. See @Matthieu Brucher's answer for proper C++ implementation.</sub>

Comment: Please, no answer with `#include <bits/c++.h>`. Same for all these global variables or C headers.

Comment: Fixed. Mind if I ask why we should avoid this header?

Comment: Because it's an implementation detail of libstdc++. There are many answers about this on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I agree global variables are bad. Should I just remove the corrected code and leave the description of the 2 problems I found ?

Comment: Let's say that you should at least give a disclaimer saying that this is far from being proper C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a C++17 implementation with classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>

class LCSMemoizer
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> memory;
    std::string_view s1;
    std::string_view s2;

public:
    LCSMemoizer(std::string_view s1, std::string_view s2)
    : memory(s1.size(), std::vector<int>(s2.size(), -1)), s1(s1), s2(s2)
    {
    }

    int run(unsigned int i1, unsigned int i2)
    {
        if(i1 == s1.size() || i2 == s2.size())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(memory[i1][i2] != -1)
        {
            return memory[i1][i2];
        }
        int sub = 0;
        if(s1[i1] == s2[i2])
        {
            sub = run(i1+1, i2+1);
            sub += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            sub = std::max(run(i1, i2+1), run(i1+1, i2));
        }
        memory[i1][i2] = sub;
        return sub;
    }
};

int lcs(std::string_view s1, std::string_view s2)
{
    LCSMemoizer m(s1, s2);

    return m.run(0, 0);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << lcs("bd", "abcd");
}
```

Also note that the usual question is not just to return the count, but also the string itself.